# Uninstall pysvn in Mac OSX 10.5

Tags: python, macos, pysvn

I installed the wrong version of pysvn in my system using the .dmg. I realized the mistake and removed the pysvn folder from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/. I don't see pysvn anywhere else on my system.

Now when I try to install the correct (older) version of pysvn the installation process stops with the message "A newer version of pysvn is already installed." Where else do I need to remove the previous installation of pysvn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else needs an answer to this I'll post the solution that worked for me. [This link](http://www.nickshubin.fine-art-collection.com/articles/mac/install_history.html) was what I was looking for. Deleting the pysvn .pkg file from /Library/Receipts allowed me to install the older version.